# Updating gradle - ./gradlew: no such file found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic2

I'm building an ionic app using Angular and Firebase.

When I try to build it by doing `cordova build android` I get an error that says:

```
* What went wrong:
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.1,11.0.1], [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

So I guess something is outdated in my `build.gradle` which has dependencies like this (in `platforms\android\app\build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

That last sentence in the error says I should run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` but when I do that in my main project directory I get the erorr:

`bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory`, however, doing `gradle -v` returns the version number `Gradle 4.9`...

I don't understand what's going on... Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: remove android platform and reinstall it!

Comment: One of the reason might be that you might be running `./gradlew` command somewhere other than the root of your project directory. Can you do a `pwd` command and see which directory you are on the terminal?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri When I run `pwd` it shows that I am in the correct directory.

Comment: @Rizwanatta I have tried removing android platform several times but it doesn't fix :/

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to update `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"` to `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1`. this is exactly what causes the version conflict, because `play-services-location` demands `15.0.1`. meanwhile there's `16.0.1` already, which would require the other version numbers updated, similarly.
... and meanwhile, there's also [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/).

on Linux, occassionally `chmod +x ./gradlew` is required, to make it executable... this file should reside inside the project's directory; `gradle -v` might return the global version number, which may differ from the version actually used by the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. When I change the analytics to `15.0.1` in `build.gradle` it just reverts back to `11.0.1` as soon as I run `cordova build android`...

Comment: @JaneDoe you might be editing the built project then and not the source project. Cordova can be a little confusing there, unless hiding away the directories in the IDE, which one should not edit.

Comment: Where would I find the source project?

Comment: @JaneDoe there is only one source project, in the topmost directory (`platforms` are the built projects). this dependency might also be introduced by some Cordova plug-in. most easy might be to recursively search for `11.0.1` in the root project... downgrading all to the same version number might also work, they just have to match each other.